# My spacebar key is not working in a Sharepoint website

Tags: sharepoint

So, really strange issue.  I'm unable to input a space in between words on one of my SharePoint (2013) sites. The space bar on my keyboard (clearly) works, but this site completely ignores it.

Any idea what would be causing this strange behavior?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved.

The cause for the space bar problem was within bootstrapSwitch.js (which converts radials to on/off switches).  The exact conflict between bootstrapSwitch.js and SharePoint is not known, nor will you receive any console errors, however removing this file allowed for the space bar to be interpreted again.