# Non-breaking spaces being inserted between each word on SharePoint 2013 publishing pages

Tags: sharepoint, content-management-system, sharepoint-2013

We have a SharePoint 2013 publishing site. Sometimes, when users edit text on the page SharePoint will insert a non-breaking space every time the user hits the space-bar, instead of a regular space. So if you view the source for that section you'll see a lot of stuff that looks like this: `&#160;Click&#160;here&#160;for&#160;more&#160;information&#160;`

As you might imagine this screws up the layout. Why is this happening? How do I turn it off?

Comment: What did you [investigated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28908332/my-spacebar-key-is-not-working-in-a-sharepoint-website)?

Comment: Well, I've confirmed that users are only hitting the spacebar when this happens, they aren't accidentally hitting multiple keys. Beyond that, I don't have any idea of how to troubleshoot this.